# Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match

Tags: api, authentication, woocommerce

code = "woocommerce_api_authentication_error";
 message = "Invalid Signature - provided signature does not match";

my api call service is:

http://cityflashsale.com/wc-api/v2/orders?oauth_consumer_key=ck_510d6109d01cd0443c639f64639948c29cf9449f&oauth_nonce=6041B7E2-58B0-457B-8B74-0591B014EEA5&oauth_signature=0aOcSarklLtBcgd1PejMmEcDgNg%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1455016751&oauth_version=1.0&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Baddress_1%5D=Jnxhshd&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Baddress_2%5D=Bsbbsga&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Bcity%5D=Babbzbs&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Bcountry%5D=Jssh&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Bemail%5D=email%40testsdk1.com&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Bfirst_name%5D=Ram&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Blast_name%5D=Bnnnn&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Bphone%5D=1111111111&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Bpostcode%5D=12343&order%5Bbilling_address%5D%5Bstate%5D=Hahahsh&order%5Bcustomer_id%5D=0&order%5Bline_items%5D%5B%5D%5Bproduct_id%5D=47&order%5Bpayment_details%5D%5Bmethod_id%5D=cod&order%5Bpayment_details%5D%5Bmethod_title%5D=Cash%20On%20Delievery&order%5Bpayment_details%5D%5Bpaid%5D=false&order%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Baddress_1%5D=Jnxhshd&order%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Baddress_2%5D=Bsbbsga&order%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bcity%5D=Babbzbs&order%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bcountry%5D=Jssh&order%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bfirst_name%5D=Ram&order%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Blast_name%5D=Bnnnn&order%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bpostcode%5D=12343&order%5Bshipping_address%5D%5Bstate%5D=Hahahsh&order%5Bshipping_lines%5D%5Bmethod_id%5D=flat_rate&order%5Bshipping_lines%5D%5Bmethod_title%5D=Flat%20Rate&order%5Bshipping_lines%5D%5Btotal%5D=10

Comment: Removing trailing slash from base request URL as mentioned in link below, might solve your issue:
https://github.com/NickIvanter/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library/commit/8315095b304fb0cdcc2caabc543c537d0c94fa78

Comment: Did you resolve it?